# Docker image is not listed though I built using maven docker plugin

Tags: docker, docker-compose, maven-docker-plugin

I have built docker image using following command. (Used com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.3.3 maven plugin). I am using Docker Tool Box in Windows.

```
mvn clean package docker:build
```

It gave SUCCESS with following description.

```
Successfully built d27ae98a8879
[INFO] Built localhost/my-tt-server
[INFO] Tagging localhost/my-tt-server with 1.1.x-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After this, if I run 'docker ps -a', it should have displayed this new image. But I am not seeing any image related to this. Hence I am not able to start/run the new image.

I am not able to run 'docker-compose up my-tt-server' using following configuration in docker-compose.yml

```
my-tt-server:
  container_name: my-tt-server
  image: localhost/my-tt-server:1.1.x-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
  - "21883:1883"
  - "28000:8000"
```

It gives following error

```
 Creating my-tt-server
    ←[31mERROR←[0m: Container command not found or does not exist.
```

I am not sure where it went wrong.

Please help me to solve this.
Looks like maven plugin is not correctly deploying the image. How to make it deploy correctly?

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>

                <imageName>localhost/my-tt-server</imageName>
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                </imageTags>
                <forceTags>true</forceTags>


            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I run '`docker ps -a`', it should have displayed this new image. But I am not seeing any image related to this. Hence I am not able to start/run the new image.

No: `docker ps -a` list the containers, not the images.
Do a `docker images` to see the list of images, and launch a container with `docker run <anImage>`.

If your image is built locally, the [`image` directive of docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image) should be:

```
image: localhost/my-tt-server:1.1.x-SNAPSHOT
```

Make sure there is no extra space at the end of that line.

Regarding the error message "`Container command not found or does not exist`", see [issue 20789](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20789):

> Turns out my issue was the volumes section was not mounting properly because on the windows version only the C:\Users directory gets mounted

or

> Turns out that those shell scripts use bash -- of course! Simply change to sh, as bash is not present, resulting in the above error

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I can see the images localhost/my-tt-server                                                            1.1.x-SNAPSHOT         d27ae98a8879        5 hours ago         705.7 MB

Comment: @PShetty You mean, you have build an image with an image name of "localhost/my-tt-server"; tag 1.1.x-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: But why it is not running as container if I run from docker-compose?

Comment: Yes..  REPOSITORY                                                                       TAG                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
localhost/my-tt-server                                                            1.1.x-SNAPSHOT         d27ae98a8879        5 hours ago         705.7 MB

Comment: If I do docker run localhost/my-tt-server:1.1.x-SNAPSHOT
no such file or directory
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..

Comment: As per comment, I checked out the project into C:\Users\XXXX\projects. again built image using maven.  I can see the updated date.  But still same error 'Container command not found or does not exist'

Comment: @PShetty I depends on the CMD of your image: what it does is not recognized/supported.

Comment: Finally solved :  By converting windows line ending to unix in docker and start.sh files.    Thanks very much VonC.

Comment: Well spotted. I will edit the answer to reflect your findings.